# Issue when adding multiple layers to react-konva container

Tags: javascript, reactjs, konvajs, react-konva

I had a problem using react-konva due to  Dom element. When I tried to add  a function to resize the screen of konva according to the size of the dom. I got this error thrown after adding layers.

```js
const checkSize = contentRect => {
   const { width, height } = contentRect;
   stage.attrs({
     width,
     height
   });
   stage.batchDraw();
 };

export default class Review extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
     this.state = { stage: {} };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const { values, colorValue } = this.props;
     imageValue = values;
   colourValue = colorValue;
    this.state.stage = new Konva.Stage({
      container: "container",
      width: 0,
     height: 0
    });
    window.addEventListener("resize", checkSize);
  }
```

it throws an error at that stage

```js
   layer = new Konva.Layer();
   stage.add(layer);
```

Error message: 
TypeError: stage is undefined

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to take that variable from `this.state` as you saved it there:

```
const checkSize = contentRect => {
   const { width, height } = contentRect;
   this.state.stage.attrs({
     width,
     height
   });
   this.state.stage.batchDraw();
 };
```